# are metrics topology equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$  are two topology equivalent metrices, prove that  $d(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) =  \sqrt{(d_{1}(x_{}, y_{}))^{2} + (d_{2}(x_{}, y_{}))^{2}} $ is a metric, topology equivalent with both $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ .

It is easy to prove that $d$ is metric. But what about second part?

Comment: Use the definition of "topological equivalence"?

Comment: Show that an open ball in $d$ is contained in some open ball in $d_1$ and vice versa.